# API GATEWAY - Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' when calling api from local host

Tags: reactjs, aws-lambda, axios, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to access a DynamoDB from a react app using Api Gateways and Lambda functions.

I made de API and tested the post method in https://apitester.com/, it works fine. I send a payload like `{"command": "getall"}` and get this response: `{"statusCode": 200, "body": "\"Hello from Lambda!\""}`

But when I call the API from the react app I get this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 
'https://9xovixi3ua.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/default/bmsa-calc-admin' 
from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request 
doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested 
resource.
```

My code looks like this:

```
async function getUser() {
  axios.post('https://9xovixi3ua.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/default/bmsa-calc-admin', 
  {
    command: 'getall'
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

From the API Gateway console I added an OPTIONS method, and then the method response header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I did a couple of things to get this to work. I added the response headers with the corresponding mapping values like [this guy does](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ZQaDNP5NdY). You can see that in the picture from the question.

Then, as in my case the API triggers a Lambda function, I added this to the return value of the function (python):

```
'headers': { 
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With'
        }
```

So, the complete return looks like this:

```
return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!'),
        'headers': { 
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With'
        }
    }
```

This is working fine, though I'm not sure I understand what is really happening, so if anyone wishes to explain more in the comments, it would be great.

Answer (score 2):

**Background:**
First we need to understand that browser uses OPTIONS method to first check the cors status of the REST resource on server side such as **allowed origin, header and methods**... Then it will send main request such as get and post...
To make your method win flight cors, you need to configure the OPTIONS repsonse header first to make it allow the corresponding header, method and origin. You can even use Postman to test whether your server return the valid options response headers.

**Within the context of API gateway, there are two conditions:**

1. If your OPTIONS method for that resource path is using **Mock** in api gateway, then you need to configure below headers in the integration response mapping:

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',

'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS',

'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With'
```

[image: manually add headers]

or you can simply use api gateway built in feature to enable cors.(make sure you select the right resource path on the left panel)

[image: overwrite cors using api gatewya]

2. If you use **lambda proxy integration** for the option method, then please return these headers in your lambda function response when event.httpMethod=='OPTIONS'

```
 if event['httpMethod'] == 'OPTIONS':
       return {
           'statusCode': 200,
           'headers': {
               'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
               'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
               'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*'
           } } # preflight cors issue
```

**After configuring OPTIONS method, You also need to make sure your main method (POST GET) allows your domain.** In your case it is localhost. You need to configure it following the above two methods based on the type of your api(Mock or Lambda proxy integration). But you can always verify it in the **integration response header** or in the **postman**

If you can understand what I have described, no matter what kind cors issues are there in the aws api gateway, you can solve it easily